# How to determine all uses of all_products in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

We have a page on a Shopify store that is triggering this error, despite very careful logic to keep the number of unique uses of `all_products` under the maximum of 20:

```
Liquid error: Exceeded maximum number of unique handles for all_products.
```

Other pages that use the same templates are working fine, so something unique about this page is causing one extra `all_products` reference. (I know it's only off by one because the error happens between what I expect to be the 19th and 20th reference to the object.)

Despite tracing through our code, I cannot figure out where the extra reference is happening. Is there any way to definitively identify where all references across a page are happening, or even just what handles have been referenced?

Comment: It will be hard to help you without any code. You will need to review your header/footer/template/layout/snippets that are used on this page in case you call `all_products` any where additionally. Test with 20 hardcoded request to check if they pass, if they don't the problem is outside the section you are sure it works, but if it pass then the section in question is the problem.

Comment: Right, I *know* the problem is outside the section I'm working on. I already looked at the header, footer, etc. (I searched the code for every use of `all_products` and traced back from there how it was included.) Evidently I missed something, but that's why my question here is whether there's a direct way to flag/log all references to the object. I'm used to non-SaaS dev environments that aren't such black boxes.

Comment: Probably a bug in Shopify... all_products is super useful, but also something we cannot control...

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this bug and it sucks.

No way to output the number in liquid I'm aware, other than using {{ increment }} after each all_products and seeing what it spits out.

In section theme settings, have worked around this a number of ways, none of which are as easy as product picker though.

Down and dirty, you could swap the product picker for a text input and have the client add the product handle there, and render it with JS.

I've found the more client-friendly approach is a collection same name as page,  have them use collection picker, and make the liquid work to populate the 20(+) products in the order you want. Have them arrange the order from within the collection.

Comment: > Down and dirty, you could swap the product picker for a text input and have the client add the product handle there, and render it with JS.

Note: When you use the product picker, the settings value is actually the handle of the product - You can drop that handle into your Javascript to load your details asynchronously, as well

Comment: Also, I definitely agree with your advice of using collections whenever possible - they're a much better way to get an arbitrary large number of products into play, and the ability to specify the sort method on collections in a variety of ways is such a nice bonus :)

Comment: In our case we're actually constructing this dynamically from products selected in a custom field (using Accentuate Custom Fields). In this case our "down and dirty" solution was to simply display fewer products (16 rather than 20), though had we had the time, AJAX would have been the ideal approach.